# Casting object to Implemented Interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

I'm having a problem with Casting an object to it's implemented Interface, across different assemblies, the Interfaces are also using Generics.

I have 3 libraries.
Contracts (Interface Location)
Implementations (Interface Implementations)
MainAssembly (Happens to be an ASP.NET MVC5 application)

Main references Contracts and Implementations. Implementations references Contracts.

Contracts Contains 2 Interfaces, one uses a generic that is of the other Interface type

```
public interface IConfig{}
public interface IStore<TConfig> where TConfig : IConfig{}
```

Implementations Contains 2 Classes that Implements these Interfaces like so.

```
public class ConfigBase : IConfig {}
public class Store<TConfig> :IStore<TConfig> where TConfig : ConfigBase {}
```

ASP.NET application Has a Class that Inherits from the ConfigBase class

```
public class Configuration : ConfigBase {}
```

Within the Contracts Library, there is a Service Class, that contains a Method that Requires a type of IStore

```
public void DoSomething(IStore<IConfig> store){}
```

However Passing in a type of Store is telling me it can't convert it. This is where the compile time error occurs, everything appeasrs to build correctly.

```
Store<Configuration> store = new Store<Configuration>();
serviceObj.DoSomething(store);
```

Comment: For that to work you'd need to make `TConfig` in `IStore` co-variant. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ahh, Thank you, I just had to change IStore<TConfig> to IStore<out TConfig>

Comment: Note you should only do that if `TConfig` is only used as output (return of methods and read only properties) and not as input (method arguments and writable properties) in `IStore`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make you generic interface **covariant** using `out` generic modifier

```
public interface IStore<out TConfig> where TConfig : IConfig{}.
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, Going to do some reading to try and fully comprehend what I just did.